# viewDidLoad being called before didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, viewdidload, didselectrowatindexpath

I have
`viewDidLoad` (of next tableView) being called before `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` (of current `tableView`).

I am using a 'singleton' to hold my model and up to now this has been working quite well. I am trying to pass on the row selected in the current table in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to the destination `tableview` (they are linked by a  segue in storyboard) by setting by the variable in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

However the `viewDidLoad` of the destination `tableview` is called before I can set the row number. `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called later but by then I have set up my data (wrongly) for the destination table.

Comment: Can you post some of your code for this?

Comment: Yes, please post some code to explain this further. It seems to me like something is going wrong with your segue (if indeed you have one) more details needed please.

Answer (score 5):

When using segues you do not need `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. You just link the segue to the cell in IB. In the code just use this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
   CustomViewController *newVC = [segue destinationViewController];
   newVC.property = theDataYouWantToPass;
}
```

You can retrieve your row through the `sender` variable that is passed.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) sender;
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
NSInteger myRow = indexPath.row;
```

Comment: Thanks Mundi, perfect. I was beginning to think I had done something really naughty. Why don't I need to use didSelectRowAtIndexPath though?

Comment: That is the legacy method, if you will. You could delete your segue in IB and use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead. When using segues it is simply not necessary - or you can do different things with it.

Comment: i wish to send the selected row data, so how?

Comment: As described above, line 3.