# didSelectRowAtIndexPath being called after viewDidLoad of the called view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [viewDidLoad being called before didSelectRowAtIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016144/viewdidload-being-called-before-didselectrowatindexpath)

I am trying to pass variables over to the new view. I have the following code:

```
appDelegate *dataCenter = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

dataCenter.myVariable = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

in the

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath
```

of the calling view. However, the issue that I have is that this variable is empty in the vewDidLoad function of the next view, simply because it fired off BEFORE the didSelectRowAtIndexPath of the calling view. I am using storyboard to link the views together. Both are UITableView.

If I hit back and then reselect the table element it is then set, granted that by the time I hit back and then selected again, the variable got set. Is there any way to for the order of execution? I really don't want to do UI view switching on the back end.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question has already been answered. Please see the possible duplicate section. I will leave this up here in case it helps someone find the right answer (if your search leads you here). Please vote to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about saving the data to an NSUserDefaults at didSelectRowAtIndexPath
And then at viewDidLoad read that saved data from NSUserDefaults.

```
-(void) didSelectRowAtIndexPath {
    NSUserDefaults *infoSaved = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [infoSaved setObject:myVariable forKey:@"myvariable"];
    [infoSaved:synchronize];

    // then call the new view to load
}
```

And in the new view that's loaded:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    NSUserDefaults *infoSaved = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    myVariable = [infoSaved objectForKey:@"myvariable"];

    // and use your variable
}
```

Hope that helps